# Transform table with rows to a scrollable list

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a scrollable list of items or divs, Right now I find a way to do it with a table but it's a horrible design.

Maybe if the table get better adjustment when I reduice the browser window, I keep the table, but now the table looks horrible for a responsive view.

I need some help or advice

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }

    table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}

table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 200px;
}

table {
    width: 350px; /* can be dynamic */
}

th
{
    width: 75px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <hr>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have fixed height for a table which creates a problem. to get `height: 100%`. have look to following code

**add this css to your code**

```
  .panel {
     height: 100%;
   }
  .table {
     height: inherit;
  }
  table tbody {
     height: 100%; !important
  }

  .sidenav {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  table tbody {
     overflow: auto;   
     /*height: 200px; remove this line from your code*/ 
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/princesodhi/sLmgdk4L/2/

Comment: I don't know why, but even after changes my table is still no scrollable

Comment: did u check it in jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/princesodhi/sLmgdk4L/2/

Comment: Yes, I got another problem, I have dateTime Picker in my header. and it does not show correctly now.

Comment: @DavidEdgar create a new question dateTime Picker if it is still not fixed. or send me a link if you already have created a question.

Comment: It worked, I just forget to accept your answer for future users.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the content in div with fixed height, and `overflow:scroll`. Example:

```
.container{
   height:350px;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8d9qkea7/

Comment: Fixed height isn't a requirement for `overflow:scroll` ;)